# Make Specific Part Bold in Google Sheets via Python gspread Api

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I have been trying to make a bold part of my cell using Gspread API. But I couldn't figure out how to do that. I found a way in that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59231487/google-sheets-api-v4-bold-part-of-cell) but I couldn't integrate to Gspread API

[That shows how I something wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OKBm.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. From `I found a way in that question but I couldn't integrate to Gspread API`, I proposed a sample script for gspread. Could you please confirm it? When my proposed script is used, I could confirm that your expected result is obtained. So, please test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to set the bold type to the text of `bold specific part` in `I would like to make bold specific part of my cell`.
- You want to achieve this using gspread for python.
- You have already been able to get and put values to Google Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```py
spreadsheetId = "###" # Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
sheetName = "Sheet1" # Please set the sheet ID.
client = gspread.authorize(creds) # Please use your authorization script.

spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(spreadsheetId)
sheetId = spreadsheet.worksheet(sheetName).id
text = "I would like to make bold specific part of my cell"
gridRange = {"sheetId": sheetId, "startRowIndex": 0, "endRowIndex": 1, "startColumnIndex": 0, "endColumnIndex": 1}
reqs = [
    {"updateCells": {
        "range": gridRange,
        "rows": [{"values": [{"userEnteredValue": {"stringValue": text}}]}],
        "fields": "userEnteredValue"
    }},
    {"updateCells": {
        "range": gridRange,
        "rows": [{"values": [{"textFormatRuns": [
            {"format": {"bold": True}, "startIndex": 21},
            {"format": {"bold": False}, "startIndex": 39}
        ]}]}],
        "fields": "textFormatRuns.format.bold"
    }}
]
res = spreadsheet.batch_update({"requests": reqs})
```

- In this sample script, a text of `I would like to make bold specific part of my cell` is put to a cell "A1" of "Sheet1", and the bold is set to the text of `bold specific part` in the cell "A1" using the batchUpdate method.

#### Result:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- If your cell "A1" has already had the text of `I would like to make bold specific part of my cell`, you can also use the following request body.

  ```
    reqs = [
        {"updateCells": {
            "range": gridRange,
            "rows": [{"values": [{"textFormatRuns": [
                {"format": {"bold": True}, "startIndex": 21},
                {"format": {"bold": False}, "startIndex": 39}
            ]}]}],
            "fields": "textFormatRuns.format.bold"
        }}
    ]
  ```

#### References:

- [batch_update(body)](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=batchupdate#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.batch_update)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

Comment: Hello, It works perfectly! It saves my day. Thanks for helping!

Comment: @Okan Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.